# Building orthonormal basis of $\mathbb{C}^4$ containing a multiple scalar of vector $(1+i,1,1,1)$.

Tags: linear-algebra

How can I construct an orthonormal basis of $\mathbb{C}^4$ containing a scalar multiple of the vector $(1+i,1,1,1)$?

I try using Gram Schmidt but i need begin with a set linearly independent containing $(1+i,1,1,1)$.

You know a set linearly independent containing $(1+i,1,1,1)$?

Comment: Take any basis of $\mathbb{C}^4$ containg $(1+i,1,1,1)$ and apply the Gram-Schmidt process starting with $(1+i,1,1,1)$.

Comment: yes Richard i think this..which is a basis of $\mathbb{C}^4$?

Comment: Take **any** basis $b_1,...,b_4$ and apply Gram Schmidt to the vectors $(i+i,1,1,1),b_1,...,b_4$. One of the vectors will be zero and the rest will be an orthonormal basis with the given vector as one of the elements.

Answer (score 1):

Try starting with
$$(1+i,1,1,1)\,,\ (1,0,0,0)\,,\ (0,1,0,0)\,,\ (0,0,1,0)\,,\ (0,0,0,1)\,.$$
This is a linearly **dependent** set containing your vector, but you can still apply Gram-Schmidt.  At some stage (maybe the last stage, maybe earlier) you will find that you get a zero vector; then you omit the vector which caused this.  For example if it happens at the third step then leave out $(0,1,0,0)$ and keep going with
$$(1+i,1,1,1)\,,\ (1,0,0,0)\,,\ (0,0,1,0)\,,\ (0,0,0,1)\,.$$

If your first four steps don't give a zero vector then you can just stop - the fifth step would have given a zero result but you know this in advance so you don't need to do the calculation.